# bash: edit file in subdirectory by date format

Tags: bash

I have a file structure like `YYYY/MM/DD.md` and I'd like to make a bash script that would run `vi` like `vi date +%Y/date +%m/%d.md` but I can't quite figure out how to create the fully qualified file path. Any tips?

Comment: What about using `vi $(date +"%Y/%m/%d.md")`?

Comment: Or, if you need, `vi /path/to/$(date +"%Y/%m/%d.md")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there - just run

```
vi "$(date +%Y)/$(date +%m/%d).md"
```

or even

```
vi "$(date +%Y/%m/%d).md"
```